# Hints to the compiler using llvm

Tags: c, compiler-construction, llvm, clang

I am working on a tool that takes the LLVM IR and modifies it. I'm interested in allowing the programmer to give hints to the compiler. For example, he can give the hint that a particular loop is compute intensive. For this purpose, one thing that comes to my mind is to use a pragma. So my question is, how can we make the pragmas work? Can I have the pragma information there in the LLVM IR? What are the options for such kind of task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question can refer to several different things:

- If you're looking to understand how to implement `pragma`, take a look at how Clang does it. I.e. what various `pragma` directives are translated to.
- If you want to understand the existing hints (for instance `inlinehint`, `byval` etc.), look at attributes - for example [Function Attributes](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#fnattrs).
- If you want something more flexible and proprietary, you can use metadata. LLVM itself uses it for various purposes, but in *your own* compiler you're very free in what you can do with it. Hints to the compiler are one possible application.

Comment: There are "`#pragma hot`" and "`__attribute__ ((hot))`" in gcc. Is there something like it in llvm/clang? Gcc uses they to get "profile feedback" without doing a "-fprofile-generate"/"-fprofile-use".

Comment: @osgx: I don't know the answer off-hand. Would have to dig in the sources to see... Generally, though, clang compiles pretty much everything gcc compiles these days. However, not sure if it replicates the functionality of all gcc-specific pragmas